# issue with the usage of BELONGSTOMANY or HASMANY on sequelize

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've been using NODE.JS - SEQUELIZE to deal with POSTGRES database. But, it's been a while that I am facing an issue.

I have two TABLES:

FIRST TABLE: **Purchases**. Inside of this table, there is a column which keeps the foreign key of the Products table, because they are associated. But, as long as I'veen been coding, I realized that I needed to "insert" more than one products at once, like an array, for those people who will buy more than one product at once.

SECOND TABLE: **Products**.

I want something like this => Allow to a purchase inside of **Purchases** to have more than one products associated with. But all that I can do is make the product foreign key column in purchases table accepts only intenger (ID) of only one product.

For exemple:
The user X buyed multiple products, so then in **product** in **Purchases** will have the products [1,3,5] and these numbers are the product's ID that I would like to associate with the **Products** table.

print of the PURCHASES MODEL: [purchases MODEL(not the migration) on sequelize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QjRky.png)

print of the PURCHASES TABLE: [purchases table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsfkF.png)

print of the PRODUCTS TABLE: [products table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTcEe.png)

The conclusion I've have reached was using "Belongs to MANY" or "Has many", but I don't how.

Thanks.

Comment: why is this tagged mysql?

Answer (score 0):

I propose you to add another table to achieve multiple products in one order:

1. ORDER table - stores one record per a customer order (all columns that related with an order as a whole)
2. ORDER_ITEMS - stores items inside each order (columns: a link to ORDER, a link to PRODUCT, a quantity, a price and other related columns (a discount and so on)
3. PRODUCT - stores a catalog of products to buy